# convert data frame in r to transactions or an itemMatrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, apriori

I have a data that in `data.frame` format I want to convert  it into `transactions` or an `itemMatrix`.

Inspects function in `arules` support these two data format that's why I'm asking this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(arules)
```

### example 1: creating transactions from a matrix

```
a_matrix <- matrix(
      c(1,1,1,0,0,
    1,1,0,0,0,
    1,1,0,1,0,
    0,0,1,0,1,
    1,1,0,1,1), ncol = 5)
```

### set dim names

```
dimnames(a_matrix) <-  list(
    c("a","b","c","d","e"),
    paste("Tr",c(1:5), sep = ""))

a_matrix
```

### coerce

```
trans2 <-  as(a_matrix, "transactions")
trans2
inspect(trans2)
```

### example 2: creating transactions from data.frame

```
a_df <- data.frame(
    age = as.factor(c(6,8,7,6,9,5)), 
    grade = as.factor(c(1,3,1,1,4,1)))
```

### note: all attributes have to be factors

```
a_df
```

### coerce

```
trans3 <- as(a_df, "transactions") 
image(trans3)
```